# centos bash syntax "-bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe" centos 5.5

Tags: linux, bash, centos5

I'm trying to send fwknop SPA from linux command. The syntax is

```
echo 1234 | fwknop --Home-dir /tmp -f 5 -A tcp/80 -a $1 -D google.com > /devel/null 2>1 &
```

However I'm getting  an error like "-bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe" 
  If I try the same command from another centos it works without any issue so I don't know how to fix it. The both servers are running the same version of centos (5.5) with the lasted updates.
Thanks a lot for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/devel/null`

shouldn't this be `/dev/null`?

also, check the installed packages and try running `fwknop` without redirection (no echo or `/dev/null`). The command may be failing